# Rails NoMethodError in Organizations#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am currently building a rails app which has the user log into a dashboard and fill out a form. I am getting this error:

```
NoMethodError in Organizations#new
Showing C:/Users/ali/Desktop/Sites/xxx/app/views/users/_dashboard_nav.html.erb where line #7 raised:

undefined method `organizations' for nil:NilClass
```

UserController.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def index
        @user = current_user
        # @organization = current_user.organization.all
    end

    def show
    end

end
```

_dashboard_nav.html.erb

```
...
 <% if @user.organizations.exists? %>       <-- This is line 7
     <%= link_to "Profile", edit_user_organization_path(@user, @organization), class: "dashboard-nav__item" %>
 <% else %>
     <%= link_to "Profile", new_user_organization_path(@user, @organization), class: "dashboard-nav__item" %>
 <% end %>
...
```

organization.rb

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :organizations
  has_many :form_submissions
end
```

I know that something isn't defined, or an object isn't being passed somewhere, but I just cannot wrap my head around the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `current_user` is not present 
make sure that you are logged in so that `current_user` will have some value

Also change index method

```
def index
    @user ||= current_user
    # @organization = current_user.organization.all
end
```

Comment: current_user is present, I am logged in.

Comment: well, it seems that somehow `current_user` is `nil`

Comment: can you add breakpoint at index method and check value of `current_user` variable

Comment: I just used byebug in the index method right above the `@user ||= current_user`, and the value of @user is nil.

Comment: @aishaq11 You should check value of `current_user` not `@user`

Comment: current_user is actually returning the correct value.

Comment: did you pass @user to partial while rendering ?

Comment: Not that I can remember no I have not.

Comment: in your index.html 
you can do something like this `<%= render :partial => 'dashboard_nav', :locals =>  { :user => @user } %>` and then use `user.organizations.exists?`

Answer (score 2):

```
undefined method `organizations' for nil:NilClass
```

This error message says that, you have called `organizations` method on a `NilClass` object i.e. `nil` in this case.

So, somehow, when you call: `<% if @user.organizations.exists? %>`, your `@user` instance variable has a value `nil`. That's why you are getting this error.

I would suggest you to use some debugging tool such as [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and put a `binding.pry` inside the controller action and verify if your `current_user` method is working correctly or not.

```
def index
  require 'pry'
  binding.pry # at this point, in the console, see what current_user returns
  @user ||= current_user
  # rest of your code
end
```

#### Update

You set the `@user` in your `index` action. So, `@user` will be available in the `index.html.erb`. But, you are trying to use `@user` in a different view. Make sure you have `@user` defined in the corresponding controller action and it will work after that.

As `NEO-xx` also mentioned in his comment, try to pass the `user` to the partial using `locals`:

```
<%= render :partial => 'dashboard_nav', :locals => { :user => @user } %>
```

Then, you should be able to access the `user` in your partial:

```
<% if user.organizations.exists? %>
```

Comment: I just used byebug in the index method right above the `@user ||= current_user`, and the value of @user is nil. Guess I found my problem, but why?

Comment: check the value of `current_user` method. I suspect that's returning `nil`. dig into that why that's not returning the current user value.

Comment: current_user is actually returning the correct value.

Comment: I think I know what's going on. So, you set the `@user` in your `index` action. So, `@user` will be available in the `index.html.erb`. But, you are trying to use `@user` in a different view. Make sure you have `@user` defined in the corresponding controller action and it will work after that.